# Statically linking Python, but still supporting external .pyd modules

Tags: python, c++, windows, visual-c++, dll

I'm looking at statically link Python with my application. The reason for this is because in some test cases I've seen a 10% speed increase. My application uses the Python C-API heavily, and it seems that Whole Program Optimization is able to do some good optimizations. I expect Profile Guided Optimizations will gain a little more too. This is all being done in MSVC2015

So far I've recompiled the pythoncore project (python35.dll) into a static library and linked that with my application (let's call it myapp.exe). FYI other than changing the project type to static, the only other thing that needs doing is setting the define Py_NO_ENABLE_SHARED during the static lib compile, and when compiling myapp.exe. This works fine and it's how I was able to obtain the 10% speed improvement test result.

So the next step is continuing to support external python modules that have .pyd files (which are .dll files renamed to .pyd). These modules will have been compiled expecting to dynamically link with python35.dll, so I need to provide a workaround for that requirement, since all of the python functions are now embedded into myapp.exe.

First I use a .def file to export all of the public Python functions from myapp.exe. This works fine.

The missing piece is how do I create a python35.dll which redirects all the calls to the functions exported from myapp.exe.

My first attempt is using DLL forwarding. I made a custom python35.dll which has a .def file with lines such as:

```
PyArg_Parse=myapp.PyArg_Parse
```

In theory, this works. If I use Dependency Walker on socket.pyd, it correctly opens my python35.dll and shows that all the calls are being forwarded to myapp.exe.

However when actually running myapp.exe and trying to import socket, it fails to load the required entry points from myapp.exe. 'import socket' in Python will cause a LoadLibrary("socket.pyd") to occur. This will load my custom python35.dll implicitly. The failure occurs while trying to load python35.dll, it's unable to find the entry points for it's forwards. It seems like the reason for this is because myapp.exe won't be part of the library search path. I seem to be able to verify this by copying myapp.exe to myapp.dll. If I do that then the python35.dll load works, however this isn't a solution since that will result in 2 copies of the Python enviroment (one in myapp.exe, one in myapp.dll)

Possible other avenues I've also looked into but haven't found the right solution for:

- Somehow getting .exe files to be part of the library search path
- Using Windows manifest/configuration to redirect the library somehow
- Manually using declspec(naked) and jmp statements to more explicitly wrap the .dll. I'm working in x64, so I don't think that's possible anymore?
- I could manually do the whole Python API and wrap each function manually. This is doable if I can find a way to create the function definitions of all the exports so it's not an insane amount of manual work.

In summary, is there a way to redirect/forward calls to a .dll to functions/data exported from an .exe. Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just create a different `myapp.exe` that (also) used `python35.dll` for most of its functionality (essentially the old renamed `myapp.exe`)?

Comment: Interesting, you are saying combine all of python and all of myapp's functionality into python35.dll, right? Yes that seems like it would work... Thanks for the idea! Still, I wonder if there is a more formal way of doing this...

Comment: Yes, that was my suggestion of a workaround. As for a "formal" way, perhaps there's a way to make a even more "static" version of the Python interpreter that has all of the built-in modules statically linked into it, then maybe you could build and utilized that (assuming it would still be able to import/load other non-linked-in modules dynamically).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with the solution that @martineau suggested in the comments, which was to put all of my application, including Python, into a single .dll instead of an .exe. Then the .exe is just a simple file that calls into the .dll and does nothing else.